# convert() function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here i have sql server query (creating view) as shown below:

Example:

```
create view v1 
as 
select distinct 
         table1.col1,table1.col2,table1.col3,
         table2.col1,table2.col2,table2.col3,
         CONVERT(varchar, table2.col4, 106) AS newcol, /*table2.col4 is datetime type*/
from table1;
```

Q: How to use convert() function used above in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you simply want [`TO_CHAR()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), something similar to;

```
select distinct 
     table1.col1,table1.col2,table1.col3,
     table2.col1,table2.col2,table2.col3,
     to_char(table2.col4, 'DD mon YYYY') AS newcol,
...
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1965).

Comment: Thank you so much. One confusion here: how to format time? Because it is of datetime datatype.

Comment: @Meem The linked TO_CHAR() docs have time formats too, but from memory `HH24:MI:SS` should format in military time and `HH12:MI:SS AM` should give 12 hour time.

Comment: Yup! Thank you so much for your valuable assistance and also for SQL Fiddle.